# Python: __setattr__ for old-style classes?

Tags: python, legacy-code

How can I perform the equivalent of __setattr__ on an old-style class?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set an attribute using `setattr` ?

Comment: yes, or any equivalent method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is set the attribute for an instance of old style class, you can use the [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) built-in function, it should work for old-style classes as well . Example -

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self,blah):
...             self.blah=blah
... 
>>> foo = Foo("Something")
>>> foo.blah
'Something'
>>> setattr(foo,'blah','somethingElse')
>>> foo.blah
'somethingElse'
```

You should use the built-in function for instance any type of class.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116/mark-harrison) accepts "...equivalent methods," I'd like to demonstrate the proper means of implementing the special `__setattr__()` method in old-style classes.

### tl;dr

Use `self.__dict__[attr_name] = attr_value` in the `__setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value)` method of an old-style class.

### `__setattr__()` Meets Old-style Class

Interestingly, both Python 2.7 and 3 *do* call `__setattr__()` methods defined by old-style classes. Unlike new-style classes, however, old-style classes provide no default `__setattr__()` method. To no one's surprise, this hideously complicates `__setattr__()` methods in old-style classes.

In the subclass `__setattr__()` of a new-style class, the superclass `__setattr__()` is usually called at the end to set the desired attribute. In the subclass `__setattr__()` of an old-style class, this usually raises an exception; in most cases, there *is* no superclass `__setattr__()`. Instead, the desired key-value pair of the special `__dict__` instance variable must be manually set.

### Example or It Didn't Happen

Consider a great old-style class resembling the phrase "The Black Goat of the Woods with a Thousand Young" and defining `__setattr__()` to prefix the passed attribute name by `la_`:

```
class ShubNiggurath:
    def __setattr__(self, attr_name, attr_value):
        # Do not ask why. It is not of human purport.
        attr_name = 'la_' + attr_name

        # Make it so. Do not call
        # super(ShubNiggurath, self).__setattr__(attr_name, attr_value), for no
        # such method exists.
        self.__dict__[attr_name] = attr_value
```

### Asymmetries in the Darkness

Curiously, old-style classes *do* provide a default `__getattr__()` method. How Python 2.7 permitted this obscene asymmetry to stand bears no thinking upon – for it is equally hideous and shameful!

**But it is.**